# Private Property - Object Oriented PHP

Tags: oop, private, access-modifiers

I am a beginner in Object Oriented Programming. I am confused with a variable being declared as PRIVATE.

```
  <?php
   class dog {
        private $Name;
    }

    class poodle extends dog { 
        public function test($test){
            $this->Name = $test;
        }
    }

    $poppy = new poodle;
    $poppy->test("test");
    echo $poppy->Name;
?>
```

As I've read, "Private variables can only be accessed by the exact class that owns them - child classes cannot access private parent functions variables"

My question is if $Name is a private property, why was the output of the script returned "test" ? Shouldn't it have output an error message since another class is trying to access a private property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty straight forward. If you do a `var_dump` output on the `$poppy` object, you will notice why it will output `test` anyhow.

```
object(poodle)[1]
  private 'Name' (dog) => null
  public 'Name' => string 'test' (length=4)
```

PHP is a dynamically typed based language, which can allocate variables in runtime without the need to declare space first. Because the property `$Name` doesn't exist in the object `poodle` (in class dog you declared it *private* making it not available for inheritance), it creates (declares) one on the fly (by default, non-existing variables become *public*).

This gives the illusion as if the property `$Name` of the object `$dog` was indeed set.